# keep angular cli development application running in the background on the server ?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am running a angular cli development on a remote server, would it possible to run this development application in daemon mode?  like what we use in forever.js

Answer (score 8):

I'm running it like this on Linux. I'm unfamiliar with forever.js, but this may help.

```
nohup ng serve 2>&1 >> /var/log/ng.log &
```

Answer (score 6):

I know I am late to the party, but if your linux distro uses systemd you can setup a systemd service file. Start by creating a service file:

```
nano /lib/systemd/system/myApp.service
```

Example:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyWeb Application
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/path_to_app/
ExecStart=/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --watch --configuration=dev
CPUAccounting=true
CPUQuota=50%
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryLimit=1024M

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you can use your default service commands:

```
systemctl enable myApp
systemctl restart myApp
systemctl start myApp
systemctl stop myApp
systemctl daemon-reload
```

I had to specify an absolute path to `ng`, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

using pm2
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

how to run:

```
cd my-angular-app
pm2 start --time --name="my-angular-app" ng -- serve
```

to view logs

```
pm2 logs my-angualar-app
```